# Android ScrollView onScrollBeginDrag and onScrollEndDrag not working

Tags: react-native

> when I set onScrollBeginDrag and onScrollEndDrag, it's doesn't work. Does this property not support in Android?

```
<ScrollView
 horizontal={true}
 showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
 pagingEnabled={false}
 scrollEventThrottle={16}
 iosalwaysBounceHorizontal={false}
 onScrollBeginDrag={this._onScrollBeginDrag}
 onScrollEndDrag={this._onScrollEndDrag}
 onScroll={this._onScroll}
 ref='_scroll'>

_onScrollBeginDrag=()=>{// do something};
_onScrollEndDrag=()=>{// do something};
```

Comment: Have you found a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunaly, I was not able to use `horizontal` mode and `onScrollBeginDrag` / `onScrollEndDrag` events.

Remove `horizontal` and it will works...

I have not found any true workaround for now. But you can use `onMomentumScrollBegin` / `onMomentumScrollEnd`.

Answer (score 0):

use the ScrollView provided by react-native-gesture-handler

i had the same problem and it worked for me.